# Wrong Email in Cloud One Set-Up

Tags: email

So i typed the wrong email into the Cloud One set-up on my new Windows phone.  I've tried adding correct email addresses, but they just get added underneath the main Microsoft account (incorrect). It appears this account is what is linked to the Windows store and affects me downloading apps.  The problem is that the Microsoft account is stuck in limbo.  It has sent an email to the account to activate, but i do not receive it (wrong email).  When I select the email from the Settings page, there is an option to correct the typo in the email, however, it sends me to a page that says "There's a temporary problem."  Its been saying this for the last few days, which makes me believe it is more of a permanent problem than temporary.   Any help in deleting this account OR being able to fix the email address would be greatly appreciated.

The concern I have is my contacts.  Its been suggested that I backup my phone through OneCloud, and then delete the account.  I have never been able to access OneCloud due to my mistyping of the email in initial setup.  Is there a reliable way to backup contacts without having OneCloud?  I can not get apps to my phone without the initial OneCloud setup either.